# Equality-constrained QCQP with non-negativity constraints

Tags: matrices, optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

Given symmetric matrix $N \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{X \in \Bbb R^{n \times k}}{\text{minimize}} & \mbox{tr} \left( X^T N X \right)\\ \text{subject to} & \left\Vert e_i ^T X\right\Vert_2^2 = 1, \quad \forall i \in [n]\\ & X \ge 0\end{array}$$

where the equality constraints denote that all $n$ rows of $X$ have unit Euclidean norm. Note that $X \ge 0$ denotes that matrix $X$ is non-negative.

How can I find the optimal $X$? Analytical or iterative solutions are welcome.

---

**Background**

The application is to group $n$ sensor nodes in $k$ clusters based on their reading correlations and see if this matches up with their geographical positions. I'm not certain that this is the right approach, but I'm actually using what I'm calling the "noise matrix" obtained entry-wise from the correlation matrix,

$$N = {1-corr^{2}}$$

as a proxy for distance. The idea is to cluster the nodes so that total noise within the clusters is minimized.

The matrix $X$ is introduced as a smooth $k$-partition of the nodes so that I can initialize a random partition and apply gradient descent from there. I expect to attain a matrix $X$ with canonical unit vectors for rows, fully separating the clusters. It may be helpful, therefore, to assume that the columns of $X$ are orthogonal.

The clustering obtained this way is not guaranteed to be optimal so I wonder if there is a closed-form solution or a particular way of initializing $X$ and applying gradient descent that ensures an optimal clustering.

Comment: Have you considered $Y := X X^T$?

Comment: $N$ is obtained from the correlation matrix entry-wise as $(1-c_{ij}^2)$. I don't know much about the eigenvectors of correlation matrices, much less this noise matrix, so personally I'm not assuming $N\succeq0$

Comment: I haven't considered $Y:=XX^{T}$. This seemed like a very large space to explore, though your comment about the cyclic trace makes this interesting.

Comment: It would be a semidefinite program in $Y$. At the end, via Cholesky decomposition, one would try to find $X \geq 0$. No guarantee that the solution of the SDP is the solution of the original optimization problem, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: I'll have to review my SDPs and think on how $Y$ fits into this. Thanks for the lead.